# what is going on here with python globals?

Tags: python-2.7

Can somebody explain to me why the code in `fails()` throws an exception?  Is this some sort of python 2.7 auto promote to global feature?

```
glist = []

def works():
    glist.append("one")

def works2():
    for x in glist:
        pass
    glist.append("two")

def fails():
    for x in glist:
        pass
    glist.append("failbot")
    glist = []

if __name__ == "__main__":
    works()
    works2()
    fails()
```

Throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "autoglobal.py", line 20, in <module>
    fails()
  File "autoglobal.py", line 12, in fails
    for x in glist:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'glist' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, names in functions are global unless you make them local. You made `glist` local by assigning to it in one of the functions:

```
def fails():
    for x in glist:
        pass
    glist.append("failbot")
    glist = []   # direct assignment!
```

Anything that 'binds' to a name makes that name a local; direct assignment is one way, but a `for` loop using a name (like `x` in the above function) also makes that name local to the current scope.

Override this by adding `global glist` to the function, *or* don't assign to the name but to a slice.

The following doesn't assign to the name, for example; it instead assigns to all indices of the existing `glist` list object, replacing them with an empty set of indices:

```
def fails():
    for x in glist:
        pass
    glist.append("failbot")
    glist[:] = []  # clear the list, not rebind the name.
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that was the proper way to clear lists.